# Generate Debug Info is fixing an issue?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VC++ 6. Don't ask why. It's just required.

My debug version is working fine. But release version was looking for a different version of OpenCV library and subsequently generated an error message "can't find cxcore100.dll" (correct one: 1.1, wrong one: 1.0) So I tried to find a reason while debugging it. So I set the "Generate Debug Info" in Link of Settings. When I run the release version, it does not generate the error message any more.

I don't think this is a good sign. What can be wrong here. Any guess or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe it wasn't actually rebuilding until you changed that setting?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Release` linker configuration and compared it to your `Debug` linker configuration when looking at the project properties?  In particular, do the libraries specified in the section regarding Linker input match between the `Release` and `Debug` configurations?

Comment: @hatboyzero yeah I compared them relentlessly. Basically no difference.

Comment: @jsobo a good point. I think you might be right. But how is that possible? I tried to rebuild them several times and even manually deleted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then in the linker options for vc6 you are linking against cxcore100.lib in the release build and cxcore110.lib in the debug build. Just change them both to cxcore110.lib

ps although in more modern version of opencv there are separate release builds of the libs which end in 'd' - I don't remember what happened in v1

Comment: I hoped that was it but no it's linking cxcore.lib in release build. And I built that lib with 1.1 version. But even if you are right, why generate debug info fixed the problem?